# How I can run two threads parallelly one by one?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In C++ how i can write two parallel threads which will work one by one.For example  in below code it need to print 0 t 100 sequentially.In below code the numbers are printing ,but all are not sequential.I need to print like 1,2,3,4,5,6.....99.If any body know , try to add with sample code also.

```
    #pragma once
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;
class CuncurrentThread
{
public:
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;
    static bool ready;
    static bool processed;
    void procThread1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 2)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(mtx);
            cv.notify_one();
            if(lk.owns_lock())
                cv.wait(lk);
            cout << "procThread1 : " << i << "\n";
            lk.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    };
    void procThread2()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(mtx);
            cv.notify_one();
            if (lk.owns_lock())
                cv.wait(lk);
            cout << "procThread2 : " << i << "\n";
            lk.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    };
    static void ThreadDriver(CuncurrentThread* thr)
    {
        vector<thread> threads;
        threads.push_back(thread(&CuncurrentThread::procThread1, thr));
        threads.push_back(thread(&CuncurrentThread::procThread2, thr));

        for (auto& thread : threads) 
            thread.join();

    };
};
bool CuncurrentThread::ready = false;
int main()
{
    CuncurrentThread tr;
    CuncurrentThread::ThreadDriver(&tr);
    
}
```

Comment: Why do you need two threads to write sequentially? What should each thread do then? Maybe your problem is that before the second thread is created, the first already finishes? In that case add some waiting/lock/sleep to the first thread to start them together.

Comment: Do you mean that each time thread 1 prints 1 then thread 2 prints 1 then thread 1 prints 2 ... etc? In any case why let two threads be that tightly coupled? Maybe you want to explain what you want to do because this doesn't seem like a right solution.

Comment: @PepijnKramer no i updated the question.To print like 1,2,3,4,5....99

Comment: Not related to your question. But `#pragma once` is something you will use in a header and `using namespace std;` is something you don't want to use and especially not in a header. ([Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721))

Comment: If you want to force two threads to run in lockstep you should be using just one thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ready` variable as a condition for condition variable.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

class CuncurrentThread
{
public:
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;
    static bool ready;
    //static bool processed;
    void procThread1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 2)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(mtx);
            // cv.notify_one();
            // if(lk.owns_lock())

            // wait until this condition is true i.e. until ready is false
            cv.wait(lk, [&]() { return !ready; });
            cout << "procThread1 : " << i << "\n";

            // set ready to true and notify waiting thread
            ready = true;
            lk.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    };
    void procThread2()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lk(mtx);
            // cv.notify_one();
            // if (lk.owns_lock())

            // wait until this condition is true i.e. until ready is true
            cv.wait(lk, [&]() { return ready; });
            cout << "procThread2 : " << i << "\n";

            // set ready to false and notify waiting thread
            ready = false;
            lk.unlock();
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    };
    static void ThreadDriver(CuncurrentThread* thr)
    {
        vector<thread> threads;
        threads.push_back(thread(&CuncurrentThread::procThread1, thr));
        threads.push_back(thread(&CuncurrentThread::procThread2, thr));

        for (auto& thread : threads) 
            thread.join();

    };
};
bool CuncurrentThread::ready = false;
int main()
{
    CuncurrentThread tr;
    CuncurrentThread::ThreadDriver(&tr);
}
```

Link where I tested this: https://godbolt.org/z/4jEns16oq

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a valid use case for using two threads like this, here is an example. I prefer using std::async over std::thread it has better abstraction and information exchange with the main thread.
The example is written for 2 threads but can easily be changed to more threads.

Live demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/eQex9o_nMz

```
#include <future>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

// Setup a helper class that sets up
// the three things needed to correctly
// use a condition variable
// 1) a mutex
// 2) a variable
// 3) a condition_variable (which is more of a signal then a variable)
//
// also give this class some functions
// so the the code becomes more self-explaining

class thread_switcher_t
{
public:
    void thread1_wait_for_turn()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
        m_cv.wait(lock, [&] {return (thread_number==0); });
    }

    void thread2_wait_for_turn()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
        m_cv.wait(lock, [&] {return (thread_number==1); });
    }

    void next_thread()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
        thread_number = (thread_number + 1) % 2;
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

private:
    std::size_t thread_number{ 0 };
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
};


int main()
{
    thread_switcher_t switcher;
    
    auto future1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]
    {
        for(std::size_t n = 0; n <= 100; n+=2)
        {
            switcher.thread1_wait_for_turn();
            std::cout << "thread 1 : " << n << "\n";
            switcher.next_thread();
        }
    });

    auto future2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]
    {
        for (std::size_t n = 1; n <= 100; n += 2)
        {
            switcher.thread2_wait_for_turn();
            std::cout << "thread 2 : " << n << "\n";
            switcher.next_thread();
        }
    });

    future1.get();
    future2.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not seen that this will run threads in parallel. If 1 thread does 1000 iterations, even with some serious work that takes up time, it will take 200ms, let's say. If I then divide the work into two threads (async), where each one does 500 iterations, and I follow your code here, it will still take 200ms for both. Each thread will take 100ms, but they run sequential, so total time will be 200ms +/-. I want to see two threads take around 100ms.

Comment: Correct, OP asked for 2 threads to run threads "one by one' and that's what this code shows. It is also because OP's question is not really clear. So it also could mean he wants to run iterations 1,3,5,... on one thread and 2.4.6.... on the other. This too can be done with this approach